# Parital derivative simplification

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given two functions $f(x, y, z)$ and $g(x, y, z)$:

Simplify $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}g(x,y,z)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}f(x,y,z)$$

I am studying MVC on my own; I need to simplify this in order to solve a textbook problem, but I have no idea where to begin—I think there must be some result that simplifies this easily,  that I must have missed bc I am studying by myself.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You may use product rule.

Answer (score 1):

By the product rule,

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (f.g) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} g(x,y,z)+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} f(x,y,z)$$

I hope that is the simplification you were looking for.